# Django SyntaxError while using XLSXWRITER

Tags: django, xlsxwriter

I'm using xlsx writer in django to write some data in an excel file for users to download, but I keep getting a syntax error in my views.py file. Here is the functions thats raising the error:

```
def excelr(request):
    user = getuser(request)
    registrations = Registration.objects.filter(MUN = user)
    path = str(f"registrationsdb/{user.username}{str(datetime.now())}registrations.xlsx")
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(path)
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    worksheet.write(0,0, 'Delegate Name')
    worksheet.write (0,1, 'Age')
    worksheet.write(0,2, 'Instiution')
    worksheet.write (0,3, 'Email - ID')
    worksheet.write(0,4, 'City')
    worksheet.write(0,5, 'Experience')
    experience=[]
    for row in registrations:
        dele = row.delegate
        exp = Experience.objects.filter(delegate = dele)
        experience.append(exp)
    for i in range(0, len(registrations)):
        worksheet.write(i+1,0, str(registrations[i].delegate.name))
        worksheet.write(i+1,1, str(registrations[i].delegate.age))
        worksheet.write(i+1,2, str(registrations[i].delegate.institution))
        worksheet.write(i+1,3, str(registrations[i].delegate.email))
        worksheet.write(i+1,4, str(registrations[i].delegate.city))
        worksheet.write(i+1,5, str(expstring(exp[i]))
    workbook.close()
    return path
```

In the abover **expstring(arr)** returns a string value. I'm having errors raised post the line with **workbook.close()**
(This function returns a path to the views.py route function to create a download link for on my html)
I've installed all the required packages but cant seems to figure out the fix. Looking for some help on the same.

EDIT: Here is my error traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://www.sample.com/

Django Version: 3.1
Python Version: 3.8.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'MUNbase']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 165, in _get_response
    callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs = self.resolve_request(request)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 288, in resolve_request
    resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 545, in resolve
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 582, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
    <source code not available>
  File "/opt/bitnami/projects/PROJECT/PROJECT/munbase/urls.py", line 24, in <module>
    path("", include("MUNbase.urls"))
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
    <source code not available>
  File "/opt/bitnami/projects/PROJECT/PROJECT/MUNbase/urls.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import views

Exception Type: SyntaxError at /
Exception Value: invalid syntax (views.py, line 430)
```

Thanks

Comment: Please add the error/warning with backtrace to the end of the question.

Comment: Done. I've added the error traceback